# How to backup Hive databases

Tags: hive, hadoop2

As we are going format the whole cluster, I need to backup all my hive databases.

Is there any simple way to do this?

We are using Hive 1.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

1. Back up the metastore database
2. Back up all the files in the Hive warehouse (typically /user/hive/warehouse).

But you have backed up all your files anyway, I presume?

Comment: I know how to export a table / partition to the file system. But I have a lot a tables per database, some of them have a lot of partitions. Is there anyway to backup a whole database?